Computing a limit for variable $a\in\mathbb{R}$ using measure theory
So I have this exercise and solutions to it, and lots of questions in bold:
Exercise
Compute the limit
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{a}^{+\infty} \frac{n}{1 + n^2 x^2} \, dx
$$
for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$.
Recall that $\arctan x$ is a primitive of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.
Solution
Observe that
$$
\frac{n}{1+n^2 x^2} \leq \frac{1}{n x^2} \leq \frac{1}{x^2} \text{ for } x > 0.
$$
If $a > 0$, then since the function $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is integrable on $(a, +\infty)$ why is it only integrable for a>0?, we may apply Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem and deduce that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{a}^{+\infty} \frac{n}{1+n^2 x^2} dx = \int_{a}^{+\infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{1+n^2 x^2} dx = \int_{a}^{+\infty} 0 dx = 0.
$$
For $a = 0$ we can use the change of variables $y = nx$ and see that the integral is actually independent of $n$:
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{n}{1+n^2 x^2} dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{1+y^2} dy = \arctan y \bigg|_{0}^{+\infty} = \arctan(+\infty) - \arctan(0) = \frac{\pi}{2}. $$
How do I see this last equality? I mean $\arctan(0)=\frac{\cos(0)}{\sin(0)}$ is not defined? And $\arctan(+\infty)$? I am stuck.
Finally for $a < 0$ we get, by using the fact that the integrand is even:
$$
\int_{a}^{+\infty} \frac{n}{1+n^2 x^2} dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{n}{1+n^2 x^2} dx - \int_{-\infty}^{a} \frac{n}{1+n^2 x^2} dx = 2 \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{n}{1+n^2 x^2} dx - \int_{-\infty}^{a} \frac{n}{1+n^2 x^2} dx.
$$
Thus using the two previous cases we deduce that the limit is $\pi$.
So in a nutshell, my problem seems to be of geometrical nature somehow. I understand the DomConv part and the measure theory, I have done many exercises using it. But somehow the trigonometry kills me. Thanks a lot for any hints!

For your first bolded question: try to find $\int_0^\infty (1/x^2) dx$ by calculating the integral over $[a,\infty)$ and taking the limit as $a\to 0$. What goes wrong?

For the second (and last) one, review the definition of $\arctan$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions and its graph https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:Arctangent.svg

Why don't you begin with doing a substitution $y=nx$?

Let
$$
I(a) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{a}^{+\infty} \frac{n}{1 + n^2 x^2} \, dx.
$$
Since $n\to\infty$ we can assume $n>0.$ Doing a substitution $y=nx$ we get
$$
\int_{a}^{+\infty} \frac{n}{1 + n^2 x^2} \, dx
= \int_{na}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{1 + y^2} \, dy
= \big[\arctan y\big]_{na}^{+\infty}
= \frac\pi 2 - \arctan na
.
$$
If $a=0$ then $na\to0$ and $\arctan na\to 0$ so $I(0) = \frac\pi 2 - 0 = \frac\pi 2.$
If $a<0$ then $na\to -\infty$ and $\arctan na\to -\frac\pi 2$ so $I(a) = \frac\pi 2 - (-\frac\pi 2) = \pi.$
If $a>0$ then $na\to \infty$ and $\arctan na\to \frac\pi 2$ so $I(a) = \frac\pi 2 - \frac\pi 2 = 0.$

fantastic! thanks
